# Why is my array reduce function return NaN?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, reduce

I have two arrays, one array has just attributes like y in the array which contains random numbers `yIsGiven()` and one array, which is equal to the first array but with the one difference, that in this time all my attributes are y except for one, there is one z, also with random numbers `zIsGiven()`.

My goal is to count all of them together, on my first array it works perfectly, but in my second array it doesn't work just because I changed one y attribute to z and I get **NaN**.

I want to sum all values in my array up, how can i do this with `zIsGiven()`?

My app.component.html:

```
<h4>My array is in total:</h4>
<p>{{yIsGiven()}}</p>

<h4>But if I change my attribute from y to z I get:</h4>
<p>{{zIsGiven()}}</p>
```

My app.component.ts:

```
yIsGiven() {
    var temp = [
      {
        name: "Agency",
        y: 110, /* All attributes are y */
        drilldown: {
          name: "Agency",
          categories: ["APPS & SI", "ERS"],
          data: [24, 8]
        }
      },
      {
        name: "ER",
        y: 60,
        drilldown: {
          name: "ER",
          categories: ["APPS & SI", "ERS"],
          data: [7, 53]
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Direct",
        y: 60,
        drilldown: {
          name: "Direct",
          categories: ["APPS & SI", "ERS"],
          data: [31, 29]
        }
      }
    ];

    var reduced = temp
      .map(function(obj) {
        return obj.y;
      })
      .reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      });

    return reduced;
  }

  zIsGiven() {
    var temp = [
      {
        name: "Agency",
        z: 110 /* For example this is now z and not y */,
        drilldown: {
          name: "Agency",
          categories: ["APPS & SI", "ERS"],
          data: [24, 8]
        }
      },
      {
        name: "ER",
        y: 60,
        drilldown: {
          name: "ER",
          categories: ["APPS & SI", "ERS"],
          data: [7, 53]
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Direct",
        y: 60,
        drilldown: {
          name: "Direct",
          categories: ["APPS & SI", "ERS"],
          data: [31, 29]
        }
      }
    ];

    var reduced = temp
      .map(function(obj) {
        return obj.y;
      })
      .reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      });

    return reduced;
  }
```

I just can't sum up all values in my array if I just change one value but what if I have different attributes in my array which I want to sum up? It just doesn't work with array reduce, or I just can't figure it out.

I would appreciate every help, thank you!

Working:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tanetr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the variables in the array has the `y` property undefined, you can do this:

```
var reduced = temp
  .map(function(obj) {
    return obj.y;
  })
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (b === undefined) return a;
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
```

to fix the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was what I was searching for. Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Change zIsGiven to this:

```
    zIsGiven() {
    var temp = [
      {
        name: "Agency",
        z: 110 /* For example this is now z and not y */,
        drilldown: {
          name: "Agency",
          categories: ["APPS & SI", "ERS"],
          data: [24, 8]
        }
      },
      {
        name: "ER",
        z: 60,
        drilldown: {
          name: "ER",
          categories: ["APPS & SI", "ERS"],
          data: [7, 53]
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Direct",
        z: 60,
        drilldown: {
          name: "Direct",
          categories: ["APPS & SI", "ERS"],
          data: [31, 29]
        }
      }
    ];

    var reduced = temp
      .map(function(obj) {
        return obj.z;
      })
      .reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      });

    return reduced;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the objects definition, the first one has a `z` property, the others have `y` property.

And since one is `undefined` (as you are requesting `obj.y`) `undefined` plus a number gives you `NaN`

You can check that by `console.log(reduced)` after commenting out `.reduce()`

Comment: Thanks for the nice explain now I finally understood the problem!